# Remove adapter from hose Y connector

Tags: plumbing

I might have overtightened a 3/4" female hose to 1/2" adapter to a Hose Y connector and when trying to remove the adapter came off with the Y hose adapter tread. I have no idea how to separate this now.

More pics [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a33I1.jpg)

[image: Y connector]

Comment: the part on the left ... please turn it over, and post a picture

Comment: Added a link to more views of the adapter with y hose  thread thing.

Comment: the Y adapter that I have was made with hex shaped holes in the threaded brass inserts, but sadly, yours does not appear to be the same way

Comment: looking more closely at the second picture on Imgur, the hole does not appear completely round ... it could be a shadow .... is the hole round? ... it would be easier to see on the intact end of the Y adapter

Comment: Yes, it is all round.

Comment: that is too bad .... one observation for the future ... do not use teflon tape, use a garden hose washer

Comment: It still has the sticker on it. That makes it easy to return ;)

Comment: Don't even remember where and when I bought it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bet the part on the left looks like the part on the right. One can see the bearing surface on the left which contacts the ball valve. Comparing it to the right side, it appears that the insert is threaded and was unscrewed rather than the desired hex item. Consider to apply a bit of thread locker to the external threads on the item on the left, taking care to restrict it to those threads, or apply thread locker to the internal threads on the left side, without getting any on the ball assembly.

As you should never need to open that section again, red (permanent) thread locker may be a good choice. Blue (temporary) thread lock could break free. After allowing the assembly to cure for an appropriate time (read and follow all label directions), you should be able to remove the hex item as originally desired.

Comment: I haven't considered that since I actually have red Locktite thread locker. I'll try that. How long should I wait to try to disassemble the adapter?

Comment: Search engine says red Loctite cures fully in 24 hours

Comment: I'll let it cure and try to remove tomorrow. Will update.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I added the pictures to the album. Thanks!